# I try get args array from the mutation. And i still get [Object: null prototype]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, apollo-server, prisma

I try to type server by `Apollo` server, `Prisma` and `Mongodb`.
I got to the stage when trying to test API for mutation by `playground`.
I want to make a field with images URL but when I type mutation to the playground then got this
[mutation and error from the playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEPnx.png)
and when I try to print args to the console I got this

```
{
  name: 'test',
  imageInput: [Object: null prototype] { image: [ 'url_1', 'url_2' ] }
}
```

I already try use restructuring like {args} or {...args} but its not working.

Please can somebody explain to me what I do wrong? 
This is my source schemas and resolver.

schema.graphql

```graphql
    type Query {
    allProducts: [Product!]!
    product(id: ID!): Product
  }

  type Mutation {
    createProduct(
      name: String
      description: String
      price: Float 
      discount: Int
      pieces: Int
      imageInput: ProductImageInput!
    ): Product!
  }

  type Product {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String!
    image: [String]
    price: Float!
    discount: Int
    pieces: Int!
  }

  input ProductImageInput{
    image: [String]!
  }
```

schema.prisma

```prisma
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["mongoDb"]
}

model Product {
  id           String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  productImage String[]
  name         String
  description  String
  price        Float
  discount     Int
  pieces       Int
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
```

resolver

```js
const resolvers = {
 Query: {
   allProducts: async (parent, args, context) => {
     return context.prisma.product.findMany()
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    createProduct: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      console.log(args)

    // const newProduct = context.prisma.product.create({
    //   data: {
    //     name: args.name,
    //     description: args.description,
    //     productImage: args.imageInput.image,
    //     price:args.price,
    //     discount: args.discount,
    //     pieces: args.pieces,
    //   },
    // })
    // return newProduct
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args))`